# Webcam: libv4l2 & VIDIOC_DQBUF : No such device

Tags: python, opencv, webcam

I have written a python code by using OpenCV library to detect a motion. If a motion occurs, it takes a snapshot of the moving object. However my problem is this: If I execute the program on my PC (Ubuntu 12.04) everything's OK.

But when I execute the program on my BeagleBone which has Angstrom Linux running and an Us Robotics webcam device attached to it, after a while it gives the following error:

```
libv4l2: error dequeuing buf: No such device
VIDIOC_DQBUF: No such device
```

How can I solve this problem?
Regards

edit: I installed ubuntu 12.04 to my BeagleBone and everything is OK with it too. It seems like my problem is related to Angstrom image. Maybe a driver or a library (libv4l2?) problem? Any ideas?

Comment: Same `VIDIOC_DQBUF: No such device` on Arduino Yun, that was previously working with the webcam.

Answer (score 6):

I was seeing this error with Ubuntu also when the board was powered through the USB cable.  When I powered the board with a 5V supply, the problem went away.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not my solution. Because I always use a 5V supply.

Comment: same issue on my raspberry pi here...maybe my camera isn't supported

Comment: Same on Arduino Yun - it was the USB cable that was the problem, tried another power cable, it worked just fine. Apparently cheaper microusb cables have enough resistance to not allow enough power for both the computer and its peripherals (like a webcam).

Comment: @NoBugs, I had the same issue on my Raspberry Pi with Minoru 3D camera. I wonder if the problem is voltage or current? Isnt it true that the peripherals need to draw enough current from the source to work? Is there a way we can verify this? I have a multimeter but will have to use some kind of microusb adapter to measure voltage/current using that. I need this to determine the battery module capacity for it as I plan to mount these on a robot. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem. I even changed my board because of this error. But when I resorted back to my older power supply, it was gone. As simple as that.